# How to merge rows with Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, merge

I have a worksheet containing:

```
ID        VALUE1    VALUE2
--------------------------
ABC       8274
DEF       613
GHI       236
ABC                 11.13
XYZ                 173   
GHI                 999
```

I'd like to merge rows and have:

```
ID    VALUE1   VALUE2
---------------------
ABC   8274     11.13
DEF   613
GHI   236      999
XYZ            173
```

**How to do such a row merging with Excel?**

This is a little bit different from [How to merge Excel worksheets by stacking columns, using an ID column?](https://superuser.com/questions/1392648/how-to-merge-excel-worksheets-by-stacking-columns-using-an-id-column), in the sense that we only have one input worksheet, with columns already separated.

---

PS: table in CSV for easier copy/paste:

```
ID;VALUE1;VALUE2
ABC;8274;
DEF;613;
GHI;236;
ABC;;11.13
XYZ;;173
GHI;;999
```

Comment: If you want to do this in-place - VBA is the only option. If you want to do this in separate region - use PowerPivot, create pivot, or use SUMIF().

Comment: @Akina I'd like to avoid doing it with VBA programming ; I already do this with CSV files + Python programming, it works, but I was curious if there exists a way directly in the GUI, without code. PS: Could you show your method with PowerPivot / pivot?

Comment: Create pivot table using master. Get MAX() value and disable totals.

Comment: are the IDs and VALUE names unique? If so, just create a table on another sheet and use `INDEX` `MATCH` to populate the values

Comment: @AlexM Rows with same IDs should be merged. VALUE names are not unique, it can be a price, etc. so many products can have the same price

Comment: @Akina Can you give an example showing how to do this (pivot table using master)?

Comment: If VALUE names are not unique, I don't know that there's a way to accomplish this. You're saying there could be a row `ABC` with data under `VALUE1` in column `B` and another row `ABC` with data under `VALUE1` in a _different column_, and you want to be able to merge those rows to show both values?

Comment: @AlexM This is not possible, VALUE1 is always in column B, VALUE2 is always in column C. About uniqueness: if a row with ID `ABC` has VALUE1 `8274`, then other rows with ID `ABC` won't have any `VALUE1`. (Otherwise it would be impossible to merge). Maybe this is what you meant about uniqueness?

Comment: Just use a simple pivot table. Id -->Rows area; Value1 & Value2 to Values area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to consolidate the rows using the SUM function,
where the combined rows are placed elsewhere on the worksheet.

The procedure below gives the following result:

[image]

This is how I created the above:

- Click on the target column (A9)
- Position the Ribbon to the Data pane
- Click **Consolidate** in the *Data Tools* group
- In the dialog, select **Sum** from the drop-down list of *Function:*
- Select the Input range (Sheet1!$A$2:$C$7)
- Click the **Add** button to add it in the *All references* box
- Select the **Left column** checkbox
- Click OK

[image]

Similar option with LibreCalc:

[image]

Comment: Great, it was a nice case to learn about Consolidate which I've never used before! Thanks!

Comment: PS: I added a screenshot with LibreCalc too for future reference, I hope it's ok for you :)

Comment: No problem - I approved it.

Answer (score 3):

### Pivot Table

A. Go to location where you want to see your data gathered. Go to the Insert tab and click PivotTable

[image]

B. In the popup window, select your source data as the table/range to analyze, and hit OK

[image]

C. In the Pivot field lists, click and drag ID to the 'ROWS' pane; click and drag your VALUEn fields to the 'VALUES' pane.

D. Click the dropdown arrow next to 'Count of [VALUEn]' and select 'Value Field Settings'. Change 'Count' to 'Max' and hit 'OK'. Do this for all your VALUEn fields.

E. Right click any cell inside the Pivot table and select PivotTable Options. Go to the Totals & Filters tab. Uncheck the 'Show grand totals..' settings.

Here is your finished table:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Other than Data consolidation & Pivot Table, you can simply use Excel worksheet formula to summarize the data set.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter this array (CSE) formula in cell `G35`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, and fill down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($G$26:$G$31, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($G$34:G34, $G$26:$G$31), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Formula in cell `H35`:

  ```
  =IF(SUMPRODUCT(($G$26:$G$31=$G35)*(H$26:H$31))=0,"",SUMPRODUCT(($G$26:$G$31=$G35)*(H$26:H$31)))
  ```

**N.B.**

- *Fill the formula across.*
- *As an alternative you may use `SUMIF` also.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*